# Concatenating Int columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Field_Data and the data in the table looks like:

```
Date                          Track_ID          Item#
2011-02-25 00:00:00.000       70212             1
2011-02-25 00:00:00.000       70212             2
2011-03-09 00:00:00.000       70852             1
2011-03-09 00:00:00.000       70852             3
```

I am trying to get output as:

```
Date                          Final_ID
2011-02-25 00:00:00.000       70212_1
2011-02-25 00:00:00.000       70212_2
2011-03-09 00:00:00.000       70852_1
2011-03-09 00:00:00.000       70852_3
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
Select Date,Track_ID + '_' + Item# AS Final_ID
From Field_Data
```

But it gave me following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '_' to data type int.

Can anyone help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to cast the `INT` fields as `varchar`:

```
Select Date,CAST(Trakc_ID as varchar(20)) + '_' + CAST(Item# as varchar(20)) as Final_ID
From Field_Data
```

Comment: @Abe - you won last round, so now we are tied I guess.

Comment: Please don't use varchar without length. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx MSDN Article on string concatenation

Comment: @Aaron - For the case of casting an `int` this will not cause any problems though.

Comment: @Martin true, but I'm just trying to encourage good practice all around. New users shouldn't have to keep a checklist of where it's ok to leave off the length, and where it might bite them - part of the problem is they don't know all the cases where it's NOT ok. If you want to code this way and save 4 characters, please feel free, just be comfortable that I'm going to call it out every time. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Heads up for any new page visitors, in SQL Server 12+, there's a `CONCAT` function available.

```
SELECT CONCAT([Date], [TrackId], '_', [ItemNumber]) AS FinalId
FROM FieldData
```